# Remove ("active") when not visible anymore and add ("active") when visible again but this also from the bottom instead of just top

Tags: javascript, css

Hey guys my brain is afk right now so I am asking yall:

I am trying to make a reveal animation everytime the element is visible. At the moment this only works when you scroll down and make the element visible from the top. I want to extend this also for scrolling up and making the element visible from the bottom.

Can anyone please explain what I need to change in order to accomplish that?

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function reveal() {
  var reveals = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");
  for (var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++) {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var elementTop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementVisible = 100;
    var elementHidden = ;
                        
    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
    reveals[i].classList.add("active");
    }
                        
    else {
    reveals[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", reveal);
reveal();
```

CSS:

```
.reveal{
    transform: translateY(SOMEVALUEpx);
    opacity: 0;
}

.reveal.active{
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Using an IntersectionObserver might be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Add another check in your `if` statement to see if the element bottom has reached height 0 plus the `elementVisible` value.

```
function reveal() {
  var reveals = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var elementVisible = 100;

  for (var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++) {
    var elementTop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementBottom = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
                        
    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible || elementBottom > 0 + elementVisible) {
      reveals[i].classList.add("active");
    } else {
      reveals[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", reveal);
reveal();
```

I also defined `windowHeight` and `elementVisible` outside the loop, as they don't need to be redefined for each iteration of the loop.  All this happens in one single scroll.